# Use JaCoCo in Android Project with Gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, jacoco, build-error

I have an android project with Gradle 5.1.1
I want to use JaCoCo to generate HTML reports about test code coverage. I tried to follow the instructions in some articles, but all of my attempts led to errors.

All that worked for me is applying plugin 'jacoco' (Project successfully builded after that).

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
```

But as soon as i add task 'jacocoTestReport', Gradle cannot sync with files and i get this error.

That's my task:

```
jacocoTestReport {
reports {
    html.enabled true
    xml.enabled false
    csv.enabled false
    html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
}}
```

That's my error:

```
ERROR: Could not find method jacocoTestReport() for arguments [build_8kqk7qvpoocfxfydulk1p4m35$_run_closure3@1aba12a5] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

I tried using "gradlew clean build" after adding "apply plugin" in 'build.gradle'. Author of tutorial successfully added task and used this line in terminal to get jacoco report:

```
gradlew build jacocoTestReport
```

Here's links to articles i used to understand how to add jacoco to project:

https://reflectoring.io/jacoco/

https://android.jlelse.eu/get-beautiful-coverage-reports-in-your-android-projects-ce9ba281507f

So my question is: Is there a way to add Jacoco to Android Project with Gradle? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I am not very sure if this is your issue but try removing the curly braces fron the buildDir -> `html.destination file("$buildDir/jacocoHtml")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Might just be a missing copy paste, but make sure you define your function as a task in gradle, ie: task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest']) {

I followed this blog for setting my Jacoco instance in my initial projects and found it quite helpful. https://engineering.rallyhealth.com/android/code-coverage/testing/2018/06/04/android-code-coverage.html

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Jacoco is awsome and I highly recommend looking into using Danger with it for your pipelines.  The blog I posted above is great for detailing how to support multi module projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
plugins {
    id 'jacoco'
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
}

task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport,
    dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest']) {

reports.html.enabled = true

def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']

def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"
sourceDirectories.from = files([mainSrc])

def javaTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/javac/debug/classes", excludes: fileFilter)
def kotlinTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
classDirectories.from = files([javaTree, kotlinTree])

executionData.from = fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", includes: [
        "outputs/unit_test_code_coverage/debugUnitTest/testDebugUnitTest.exec",
        "outputs/code-coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected/*/coverage.ec"])
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).